# how to set id for android datagrid?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

Guys i am trying to create a data grid using EditTextand tablelayout in my android project i have been successful in creating the UI with the EditText but now i require help with setting id for each field.

[image]
i want to set id as r1c1,r1c2... etc or is there a better way to do it. i want to calculate my row total and column total.

***edit:*** also i have an add button which generates new row. so cells are generated programmatically.

Table Cell Snippet:

```
    EditText cb= new EditText(this);
    cb.setLayoutParams(params);
    cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: Do you want to set ids programatically ?

Comment: Yes yes i know its textview.setId(int i); but i need string as id so thats its easier to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way to do it with strings like "r1c1", "r1c2" etc, but there are a couple of options:

If you just need to get a valid id, you could use the static method `View.generateViewId()`. This is API level 17 though, so will only work in recent versions of Android. See here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29

An alternative would be to store references to the `EditText` objects in a two-dimensional array or list. When you need to sum up rows or columns, you'd iterate over the appropriate section of the array and go from there.

A third option would be to keep a two-dimensional array of values from each `EditText` instead of the `EditText` itself. You could do this with a `TextWatcher` like this:

```
// Creating EditText for (row,col)
// Expand size of 2D array if necessary
EditText cb = new EditText(this);
cb.setLayoutParams(params);
cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
cb.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); // So the user can only enter numbers
cb.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    mValues[row][col] = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());
  }
});
```

See these links for more details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating an xml file which contains the ids:

`res/values/ids.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="r1c1" type="id"/>
    <item name="r1c2" type="id"/>
    <item name="r1c3" type="id"/>
    //some others id
</resources>
```

And then set the id to your editText.

```
cb.setId(R.id.r1c1);
```

Another approach could be to use the [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method on your `editText`

Comment: but my problem is it would be growing more i have an add button which generates new rows.